# Skype is showing the wrong last messages

Tags: macos, skype

I have a conversation between three users. When I look into this conversation the last messages are from Friday, which is wrong. These messages are always at the bottom (appears at last). So always the same messages appears at last despite there are newer messages.

I tried to reinstall Skype but it is still the same. Has anyone also experienced this kind of problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Skype for Mac (as I presume you do), and I've had to troubleshoot contact status issues. In my notes are the following comments with respect to keeping a "detailed log:"

1. Type in any chat line:
   /setupkey *Lib/LogLevel 4
2. Then quit and restart Skype.
3. Then type in chat line:
   /resynccontacts

Other commands:

/resynclivecontacts

So you probably don't need the detailed session log, but try the resync commands.

**For a more advanced method, here is another procedure from my notes:**

1. Quit Skype completely
2. Access https://m.hotmail.com in any browser
3. You should see a "403" error page
4. Restart Skype and verify the contacts are loading

Does that help? I'm sorry that I can't elaborate on the commands and techniques, since these were methods that I found without supporting explanation.

Comment: When I enter `/resynclivecontacts` I get the info to look onto [this help page](http://www.skype.com/go/help.chathelp). But that didn't helped. I also didn't found a */resyncchat*. I also tried the second option, but here I get a white page. So I'm still getting the same wrong message at the end of the conversation.

Comment: An update is available for Skype for Mac. Perhaps it would help to install the latest, for both you and the other users. Aside from that, this appears to be an ongoing issue:  http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-Messages-Out-Of-Order/td-p/1312417/page/11

Comment: Now I copied the wrong conversation and looked what time they are. They are from the first of May. I can remember that I have one time changed the time for a test and this was the first of May. So it seems that I have to wait for the first of May and the problem should be away (or clear the history which I don't want)! Thanks for the link. I give you tick if I solved my problem.